# Как сделать, чтобы на сайте показывались вложенные страницы?

Tags: php

Допустим, на сайте есть несколько разделов. А в каждом из разделов по несколько подразделов.
Я хочу, чтобы у меня где-нибудь отображался путь, как в адресной строке. Например: Главная/раздел2/подраздел4/подподраздел10.
И чтобы пользователь мог нажать на раздел2 и перейти в его меню.
Хотелось бы понять, а как вообще делать такие адресные строки? Просто логика их создания непонятна. Создаются какие-то массивы из разделов и подразделов? Но как сказать машине, какой элемент массива я выбрал?

Comment: Вас google.com забанил?.. Море примеров по самым примитивным запросам.

Comment: Если бы я нашел решение в Гугле, я бы наверное тут не писал. Знаете толковые ресурсы, где можно найти ответ на поставленный вопрос, поделитесь ссылкой.

Comment: Уважаемый, не то возможно гуглили, тема эта называется хлебные крошки и реализаций - куча. 
https://bezramok-tlt.ru/blog/posts/hlebnye-kroshki-mnogomernogo-menyu-php--mysql/
Как пример, реализацию не смотрел.